# How do I switch css file between templates?

Tags: css, django, django-templates

Im trying to switch css files between my html templates.

This is in my base_generic html file:

```
{% block ccs %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
 {% endblock %}
```

And this is how I'm trying to overwrite it in my template:

```
{% extends "base_generic.html" %}


{% block css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/detail.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

I want it to load the detail.css file in my template but it loads the base.css on every page. I've tried different browsers (one with a completely empty cache) so it isn't a browser problem. What am I missing?

Comment: have you included `loadstatic` in the detail template? If not, it may be that it cannot find the `detail.css` and is defaulting back to `base.css`

Comment: Yeah I have. The thing is, I can add it with Chromes developer tools and it works fine. It just wont load if i just go to the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{% block ccs %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

You are using this in you base html and in another html if you want to override it then correct your CCS to css

```
{% block css %}  **in this line change css to ccs or in your base html change ccs to css **
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/detail.css' %}">
{% endblock %}
```

I hope this will work for you.